# My Asp.net solution does not work on hostgator

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting, parse-error

Every time when I try to deploy my solution on Hostgator hosting, I get the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: The file '/Olive/Default.aspx.cs' does not exist.

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="OliveProjectC.Default" %>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem? Why does this problem happen?

Comment: Pretty self explanatory error message: the file for the codebehind is not there. Check your deployment structure? FTP error, not all files copied?

Comment: no , all of the files has been copied automatically when i published the project .. what do you suggest to do?

Comment: obviously they have not since you get this error... Or at least they are not visible to the process. Did you copy to a root outside the /Olive map? Case sensitivity perhaps (not sure that should matter but you can try). Have you verified it exitsts? FTP to the folder and check that they exist.

Comment: Yes It is work when i moved all files to the root , thanx it's work finally :D

Comment: Good that it works; i converted the comment into an answer. Would you bee so kidn to accept the answer so people know it is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously they have not since you get this error... Or at least they are not visible to the process.

Did you copy to a root outside the /Olive map? Case sensitivity perhaps (not sure that should matter but you can try). Have you verified it exitsts? FTP to the folder and check that they exist. –  Pleun 21 hours ago